# 'thread._local' object has no attribute

Tags: python, multithreading, logging, thread-exceptions

I was trying to change the logging format by adding a context filter. My Format is like this

```
FORMAT = "%(asctime)s %(VAL)s %(message)s"
```

This is the class I use to set the VAL in the format.

```
class TEST:
  def __init__(self, val):
    self.test_var=threading.local()
    self.test_var.value=val
  def filter(self,record):
    record.VAL=self.test_var.value
    return True
  def setValue(self,val)
    self.test_var.value=CMDID
```

It works fine in a single threaded environment, but for a certain multi-threaded environment I get the error

```
<Fault 1: "exceptions.AttributeError:'thread._local' object has no attribute 'value'">
```

Can anyone tell me what's wrong here ?? and how to rectify?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Well, the exception is telling you that the `thread._local` object returned from `threading.local()` doesn't have a `value` attribute that you can assign `val` to. You can confirm that by adding a `dir(self.test_var)` after the `self.test_var=threading.local()` line. That returns this for me:

```
['__class__', '__delattr__', '__dict__', '__doc__', '__getattribute__', '__hash__',
 '__init__', '__new__', '__reduce__', '__reduce_ex__', '__repr__', '__setattr__',
 '__str__']
```

Indeed, `help(threading.local())` will show you the methods and attributes that do exist - `value` is not among them.

If you are attempting to *add* a new attribute, then perhaps you want:

```
self.test_var.__setattr__('value',val)
```

This will actually create the attribute and assign the value to it.

Instance attributes are not generally created simply by assigning to them, like non-instance variables are...

Answer (score 0):

The attributes of threading local are per thread. If you are creating the TEST object on one thread and running filter on another, you would get this error.

I can't quite tell what you are trying to do. If you are sure you want thread local storage, you could use `hasattr` to check for the attribute right before access.

Try this:

```
  def filter(self,record):
    if not hasattr(self.test_var, 'value'):
      self.test_var.value = 'some default var'
    record.VAL=self.test_var.value
    return True
```

Answer (score 0):

1. Uninstall Keras version in your system

   ```
   pip uninstall keras
   ```
2. Install keras version 2.2.5

   ```
   pip install keras==2.2.5
   ```

It worked for me.